# Is the RD0146 an open or closed cycle engine?

Tags: engines, engine-design

RD0146 has been in the latest family of engines being developed from both Russia and US(Pratt and whitney). However, there is a lack of clarity in estabishing whether the expander cycle engine is open cycle(bleed) or closed. Can one determine it based on basic engine parameters?

http://www.russianspaceweb.com/rd0146.html

Answer (score 3):

It's a closed loop expander cycle. They published a fluid diagram:

https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/6.2006-4904

And also explicitly state in the text:

> After  providing  the  required power to  both  turbopumps,  the  hydrogen  gas is  supplied through about 200 coaxial injectors into the combustion chamber.

Comment: Can you include the diagram in your answer? The link you give is paywalled and what can be seen is insufficient to confirm what you say.

Comment: Nope, it's not mine, I can't copy anything out of it. It's a scientific citation. You can go to a nearby library to look it up... or find other ways to get access to journal papers.

Comment: Is the [RD-0146 Flow Diagram](http://www.zamandayolculuk.com/09-4/4256083_orig.jpg) from this [page](http://www.zamandayolculuk.com/html-3/roketmotors.htm) any good?

Comment: @JCRM It's the exact same diagram. It's a vector graphic in the paper, but content-wise, it's the same. I assume that website copied it out of the paper.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I added a quote from the text that also explicitly states it's a closed expander cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Main characteristics of the RD-0146 engine

> The rocket engine is built according to the “gas-free scheme”: liquid hydrogen passing through the cooling jacket of the combustion chamber is gasified and used to drive a turbopump, and then in gaseous form enters the chamber, where it is burned with liquid oxygen
>
> Ракетный двигатель построен по «безгазогенераторной схеме»: жидкий водород, проходящий через рубашку охлаждения камеры сгорания, газифицируется и используется для привода турбонасосного агрегата, а затем в газообразном виде поступает в камеру, где дожигается с жидким кислородом
> https://helpiks.org/1-122878.html

Comment: My Russian isn't very good, but I'm pretty sure that «безгазогенераторной схеме» would be better translated as "gas *generator* free scheme".